Не прослушивается порт https
пытаюсь подключить asp.net core 8 к https. У меня есть сертификат pfx + пароль.
Подключил в Program.cs сертификат.

Сразу прописал в docker файле подписал копирование сертификата
 #See https://aka.ms/customizecontainer to learn how to customize your debug container and how Visual Studio uses this Dockerfile to build your images for faster debugging.

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:8.0 AS base
USER app
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 443
EXPOSE 80

COPY ["steklm2024.pfx", "/app/steklm2024.pfx"]

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:8.0 AS build
ARG BUILD_CONFIGURATION=Release
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["ZarplatServer/ZarplatServer.csproj", "ZarplatServer/"]
RUN dotnet restore "./ZarplatServer/./ZarplatServer.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/ZarplatServer"
RUN dotnet build "./ZarplatServer.csproj" -c $BUILD_CONFIGURATION -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
ARG BUILD_CONFIGURATION=Release
RUN dotnet publish "./ZarplatServer.csproj" -c $BUILD_CONFIGURATION -o /app/publish /p:UseAppHost=false

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "ZarplatServer.dll"] 

Собираю контейнер
 docker build -t zarplatserver:latest . 

После этого запускаю
docker run -d -p 5002:80 -p 5003:443 zarplatserver:latest
Выводится следующее в консоль

На скриншоте видно, что он слушает только http порт
Если пытаюсь через студию запустить https, то в консоли слушает оба порта и http, и https.

Подскажите где я что-то делаю не так. Цель подключить https с возможностью играться с портами через docker run.

Вставьте пожалуйста текстовую информацию текстом. Чтобы выделить блок кода используйте символы ``` на новой строке перед и после блока кода.

ПОБЕДА! Изменил код настройки Kestrel:
builder.WebHost.ConfigureKestrel(options =>
{
    var certPath = "/app/steklm2024.pfx";
    options.ListenAnyIP(1360, u => u.UseHttps(new X509Certificate2(certPath, "tets")));
    options.ListenAnyIP(1361);

});

В докерфайле изменил:
EXPOSE 1360
EXPOSE 1361

Использовал команду для запуска контейнера:
docker run --rm -p 1360:1360 -p 1361:1361  -e ASPNETCORE_HTTPS_PORTS=1360 -e ASPNETCORE_HTTP_PORTS=1361 zarplatserver:latest

